# Android Wear App full screen/locked

Tags: android, wear-os

I am working on a proof of concept for a personalized application, and I was wondering if the following was possible in Android Wear (1.0 or 2.0). Basically I would like to have an app that will always sit on top of everything in the watch, and there would be no way to exit it. This will not be a public app, and only will be used by certain people that "shouldn't" have access to anything but that app. I've seen some Kiosk mode articles but never found any examples of how those apps work, and if they do what I'm looking for. One way I was thinking is to create an Android Wear launcher that would replace the regular launcher, and just not give access to any other functions of the watch except for what I want the user to be able to do. I only found one launcher application on play store, so I am assuming it's doable but my main concern is that I need to be able to "lock" the app. Does anyone have any experience with doing something similar?

I would have a function that exits the app by typing a password - kind of like parental control, but that's next step. The most important feature is to be able to lock the user where they can only interact with the app provided by us.

All of this should ideally be done on any Wear application without rooting or writing custom ROM, but if that's the only way, I'd like to hear some options.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are better off looking at a watch with stock Android rather than Wear as Wear is running a modified version of Android. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450115/kiosk-mode-screen-pinning-in-android-wear

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything about installing stock Android on the watch. What is the support like? Would I be able to download Android image from their site and install it on almost any watch? I am guessing it would also be simpler to do the full screen app on stock Android as opposed to the watch app. Also, does it need Android OS 2 for it to work? The only thing I saw was Cyanogenmod running on the watch but I assumed it was not fully supported and only had limited features.

Comment: I what meant was to look at some knock-off Chinese smart watches which would be running (close to) stock Android. You may still need to root to get rid of malware but may be easier to develop for if watch OS is running smartphone Android APIs. Will need to hunt around XDA to see what is the best choice. Again just a option to consider.